# error en html por formulario php

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

estoy haciendo una página web con bootstrap, resulta que ingreso un formulario de contacto, en su respectivo"section", hasta ahí todo bien, pero el recargar la página esta inicia desde section id="contacto" y no desde el inicio de la página, este es el código:

```
<section id="contact" class="contact section has-pattern">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contact-inner">
            <h2 class="title  text-center">Contacto</h2>
            <div class="author-message">                      
                <div class="profile">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/profile.png" alt="" />
                </div><!--//profile-->
                <div class="speech-bubble">
                    <h3 class="sub-title">contacto</h3>
                    <form role="form" id="Formulario" action="contacto2.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Nombre">Nombres</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" placeholder="Introduzca su nombre" required autofocus />
            </div>            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Motivo">Motivo de Contacto</label>
                <select name="Motivo" class="form-control">
                    <option value="opcion1">opcion1</option>
                    <option value="opcion"2>opcion2</option>
                    <option value="opcion3">opcion3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Empresa">Empresa</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Empresa" name="Empresa" placeholder="Introduzca el nombre de su empresa" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Correo">Dirección de Correo Electrónico</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Correo" name="Correo" placeholder="Introduzca su correo electrónico" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Mensaje">Mensaje</label>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="30" class="form-control" id="Mensaje" name="Mensaje" placeholder="Introduzca su mensaje" required ></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">                
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Limpiar">                
            </div>
            <div id="respuesta" style="display: none;"></div>
        </form>
                        <div class="source">
                        <span class="name"><a href="" target="_blank">pagina</a></span>
                        <br />
                        <span class="title">web</span>
                    </div><!--//source-->
                </div><!--//speech-bubble-->                        
            </div><!--//author-message-->
            <!--//info-->
        </div><!--//contact-inner-->
    </div><!--//container-->
</section><!--//contact-->
```

que estará tan mal para que me haga esto? gracias.

Comment: fijate en javascript window.scrollTo(0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Revisa esto:

```
Que tu url no tenga seleccionado el id.
URL = ejemplo.com?#algo
<section id="algo"></section>
```

Varios navegadores guardan el scroll asi que debes de borrar el cache o des habilitarlo para que descartes este posible problema.

LA ultima es que estés haciendo un scroll con javascript